# How to create facebook type polls in android app?

Tags: android, android-activity, layout

I want to create facebook type poll to get the feedback from the user's. Each poll  option count will be different. Ex, First poll with 2 options, 2nd poll with 3 options, 3rd poll with 5 options.How to create?

[image: Facebook Poll]

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? I think some graphics might be adeqaute to clarify.

Comment: "Please provide some information or some code to refer" - thats your job here. I don't know what facebook polls even look like. Would you please update your question to reflect exactly what problem you are facing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this using a vertical LinearLayout to hold all options.
Each option would be a horizontal LinearLayout consisting of a RadioButton, a form of ProgressBar (Extend on Android default ProgressBar for this Widget) and a Button.

Comment: This should be no problem for you. If you want to hire me as an Android developer drop me message.